# Calculate volume from 3d_plot

Tags: visualization

I read [this interesting kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/gzuidhof/data-science-bowl-2017/full-preprocessing-tutorial) on kaggle. I learned that you can make a 3D plot starting from CT sections. Is there a way to calculate the volume of the lungs or other structures you plot using 3d_plot? I couldn't find any reference so I need help.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question! I'm assuming you have a bunch of points $(X, Y, Z)$ plotting the lung you want to measure. 
So your question is actually the measure of a [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull).

Checkout [scipy.spatial.ConvexHull](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html). The `ConvexHull` object has a `volumn` attribute which indicates the column of the convex hull you want. It supports N dimensions, which your question is about three dimensions.